# Can TABs be used in web forms?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, tabs

I am new to web forms. For my new project(personal) I am planning to use web forms, as it meets most of my requirement. However I am not sure whether Tabs can be used in webforms, as it is very important for my project.

I tried many sites, but all are talking about windows forms. if TAB is possible in Web Forms, kindly guide me on the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use webforms for new project. Use Asp.net core MVC.  Old .net framework won't have updates.

Comment: use bootstrap for tabs

Answer (score 0):

Well, keep in mind that just about any and all web development systems can use and adopt most if not all of the standard tools in our industry.

So, if you want to adopt and use bootstrap with webforms, you can.

So, if you want to adopt and use jQuery and jQuery.UI with webforms, you can.

So, if you want to adopt react and use that with webforms, you can.

So, if you want to adopt Angular and use that with webforms, you can.

So, if you want to adopt some other "insert your favorite framework" here, then in most cases you can use such frameworks with webforms.

So, I point the above out, since at the end of the day, then you are free to use a bootstrap tab, a jQuery.UI tab, or one from the AjaxToolkit.

In other words, you much asking the wrong question, since you have quite much near unlimited web choices.

I suppose it is however fair to ask if asp.net web forms have a native built-in tab control. And I suppose one would/might ask this question since webforms are oh so very easy to use, and along with a drag + drop controls from a toolbox, then having a built-in tab control from the tool box would be "very nice", since such a control would follow the ease that webforms are famous for, and why after so many years, we still see boatloads of questions and activity on the SO areas in regards to asp.net and webforms.

So, let's cook up a few examples.

The closest to a built-in option would from the AjaxToolkit. If you installed the aj toolkit, (you can use NuGet to do this), then you can drag in a tab control from the tool box.

It looks like this:

[image]

And, to create the above I simple dropped a tab container onto the web form.

And the resulting markup:

```
<ajaxToolkit:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0">

    <ajaxToolkit:TabPanel runat="server" HeaderText="My Tab 1" ID="TabPanel1">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <h3>This is my tab 1 area</h3>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </ajaxToolkit:TabPanel>

    <ajaxToolkit:TabPanel runat="server" HeaderText="My Tab 2" ID="TabPanel2">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <h3>This is my tab 2 area</h3>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </ajaxToolkit:TabPanel>

</ajaxToolkit:TabContainer>
```

However, often I will just drop in a radio button list, and use that in place of my table control. (I often use a Radio button list, since this built in control automatic ONLY lets you select one option).

So, in some cases, you might well just use a simple RadioButton list.

A Radio button list looks like this:

```
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" Height="40px"
            RepeatDirection="Horizontal" CssClass="rMyChoice" ClientIDMode="Static"
            AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <asp:ListItem>Upload Files</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>My Files</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

So, toss in a bit of style (CSS), and I have this:

[image]

So, one of the great features in web land, is you have a lot of choices, and often in most cases, you can "roll your own" type of UI, and do so with not a lot of efforts.

Another great choice are jQuery.UI tabs, and they work rather well.

They look like this:

[image]

And this post is already too long, but we not even touched on using bootstrap tabs.

So, long story short? Yes, you have really boatloads of options and choices.

However, out of the box, there is not a built-in tab control, but there are as noted lots of choices here.